# VueJS foldout transition for table row

Tags: vue.js, animation

I am trying to add slide up/ slide down transition for table rows. I am new to VueJS animation. Can someone tell me how can I achieve this? I found few examples for the same using fade in/ fade out rows and I tried to figure slide up/ slide down from it. But it didn't work for me. Appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks!

Table.vue

```
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<transition name="slide">
<tr class="expandable-section">
<td colspan="4">
Expand content
</td>
</tr>
</transition>
</tbody>
</table>
```

style.scss

```
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.slide-enter {
    opacity:0
}
.slide-leave-to {
    opacity:0
}
```

I am getting slide up slide down foldout section with fade animation. I need this to be only slide up and slide down animation.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you get stuck. We cannot help you code something from scratch

Comment: @tauzN I have added the code